# GFCI Wiring Question - I am confused how it worked before

Tags: wiring, gfci, pool

I have a situation which I cannot figure out.  I have a GFCI outlet near some pool equipment which feeds another set of outlets near the pool, the line hot also fed a switch for the pool light.  As follows:

From Panel - Pink (hot) and white >>>> Line Side of GFCI 
To other outlet - Pink (hot) and white.  >>> Load side of GFCI

To light switch - Pink (hot) from the Load side.

First..dont ask me why the installers used pink wire....

Second...as you can see they were feeding the hot to a lightswitch for the pool light.  Well after 10 years the gfci has gone bad and I bought a replacement 20amp one (Legrand) which I wire the same way....but it keeps tripping.

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a few pictures of te inside of the GFCI box?

Comment: You mentioned the pink (hot) from the light switch... Was it on the load side before?  There must be a white, where does that land?  Or if this is conduit does the light-switch pink run down the same pipe as either the LINE or LOAD wires?

Comment: Basically pipe, pink (hot) white, ground...to line side of gfci.  Load side of gfci pink, white down another pipe to feed another outlet. Load side had another pink pigtail to hot of light switch. Light switch had pink hot pigtail from gfci and a red that was going down the pipe to the pool light.  If the gfci tripped, both sets of outlets and pool light would not work.  When not tripped, outlets worked, pool light worked.  Wired in the same fashion the gfci keeps tripping.

Comment: Hate to say it but you might actually have a ground fault someplace that the old GFCI outlet didn't detect. Esp. in an outdoor environment insulation breaks down a bit, there always seems to be water in conduit. This will take some detective work.  I'd disconnect the first outlet downstream of the GFCI, cap off the wires, power up the circuit and see if it still trips.  Lather, rinse and repeat until you find the fault.

Comment: Seems to me when they did the initial install, they took a shortcut.  Instead of running a separate circuit for the light switch, they pigtailed the hot to provide power to the switch for the pool light from the load side of the gfci... Or they were thinking safety, ie. if the gfci is tripped then no power to the light switch for the light.  If I eliminate the pig tail to the switch, the gfci works perfecty and tests fine.  Add the pigtail to the light switch and the gfci trips.

Comment: So the down stream outlets work OK and with the light disconnected? right?  That's useful info. So now you know there is a ground fault in the lighting circuit. Time to troubleshoot that. Not knowing more about the wiring layout prevents me from giving specific instructions, but you seem to know enough to proceed on your own.   BTW, current NEC code requires GFCI protection on pool lights over 15 volts.  Not sure if that was in effect when installed, but it is now.

Comment: Have you tried bisecting the fault (turn circuit off, wire it back up to GFCI, split circuit in half so only the first half of the lights work, turn circuit back on, see if GFCI trips...if it does trip, then you know the fault's in the first half and can repeat the process, splitting the first half in half, and if it doesn't trip, you can repeat the process with the second half wired back in then split in half)

Comment: I'm very confused. Where does the pool light get its neutral?  You've only talked about the pool light's pink hot.  Is the red wire (post-switch to the pool light) the only wire in that pipe?  Without understanding where the light gets its neutral,  it will be impossible to understand what's happening with this GFCI.

Comment: I think George has it and should make his comments into an answer , ground fault in the light.  pink and white , no problem sometimes the red I order looks more pink to me but any color other than white gray or green can be a hot,  the type of lights or fixture even a problem at the switch.

Comment: What makes you think the old GFCI is starting to go bad?